# Unable to submit feed in sites like friendfeed and feedage

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, curl, rss

I am trying to submit this feed "http://extremesportsblog.com/feed/" in sites like friendfeed and feedage but they are showing errors like 404 and feed cannot be downloaded.

I have verified my feed using feedvalidator.org and it is validated.

Also I am using wordpress and the xml file for the feed is dynamically generated by rss plugin.

So, any ideas??Help.

Comment: what plugin do you use? I was able to subscribe in in google reader

Comment: this is strange, do you see any other errors?

Comment: hi everyone, the problem seems to occur on the way the request was made for the url "http://extremesportsblog.com/feed" by the feedage and friendfeed for feed addition process. Any ideas on backend language used by above sites??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a funny issue.

First of all, we've tried to get your feed using `wget` (which can be the tool chosen by those feed sites for the task). Unfortunately, that leaded to a 404.

```
~  wget http://extremesportsblog.com/feed/ 
--2012-06-26 22:37:47--  http://extremesportsblog.com/feed/
Resolving extremesportsblog.com (extremesportsblog.com)... 174.120.155.106
Connecting to extremesportsblog.com (extremesportsblog.com)|174.120.155.106|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2012-06-26 22:37:48 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

However, we've succeed with a regular browser or even `curl`.

```
~ curl  http://extremesportsblog.com/feed/  -v
* About to connect() to extremesportsblog.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 174.120.155.106... connected
> GET /feed/ HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4  libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Host: extremesportsblog.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

The only real difference between them, is the `user-agent` string. 
So, what happens if we try `wget` again, with another `user-agent` string?

```
wget -U "Y U HATE ME" http://extremesportsblog.com/feed/  -v 
--2012-06-26 22:45:05--  http://extremesportsblog.com/feed/
Resolving extremesportsblog.com (extremesportsblog.com)... 174.120.155.106
Connecting to extremesportsblog.com (extremesportsblog.com)|174.120.155.106|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
```

It seems that your Apache does not fall in love with wget ;). I suggest you take a look in your config files if Apache distinguishes user-agents.

Comment: thanx....the issue occured due to settings(.htaccess) in my security plugin that redirects to a 404 if no user string found...

Answer (score 1):

Might be there is some issue with your .htaccess.. not sure though.. but here is what you can do..

Go to http://feedburner.google.com and burn your feed over there and it will give another feed URL. Just use it.

Hope that helps. Tried with your feed URL for feedburner and it worked ;) http://feeds.feedburner.com/extremesportsblog/LIXh

Hope i get the +50 ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have already used feedburner and yahoo pipes and it readily accepts it as a feed. I found this problem only with friendfeed and feedage and some of the rss directories.

Comment: Also to get the +50, you must give me a solution for friendfeed or feedage. Thankx

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your feed's type is Atom so it could be that Friendfeed and Feedage erroneously try to interprete it as RSS. For a quick test try http://atom2rss.semiologic.com/ which is an online atom to rss converter and see if sending feed in RSS format solves the problem.

Furthermore on http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fextremesportsblog.com%2Ffeed%2F you get a warning on line 33 for the object tag. Try temporarily removing it and see if it affects friendfeed and/or feedage.

Also check http://www.intertwingly.net/wiki/pie/Rss20AndAtom10Compared for a quick overview/reference of the differences between RSS and Atom. Especially the part mentioning '*Atom 1.0 in basic form is widely supported. Many aggregators fail on feeds that do not resemble the structure of an RSS 2.0 feed closely.*'

Comment: Thanks George for your valuable reply. But the problem seems to be something else as I get a 404 error on feed submission on these sites.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set "application/atom+xml" as content type, rather than text/xml