# Why will Apache serve locally to Firefox, but not VBScript?

Tags: windows, apache, vbscript, apache2, localhost

I installed Apache 2.2.  I can load local web pages using either 127.0.0.1 or 192.168.1.7 with Firefox.  (The web pages I am loading are stored on my hard drive.)  When I try to access those addresses with VBScript, it doesn't work.  If I access the web with VBScript, it works fine, including if I use IP address in the domain name.

Here's the VBScript that won't work on a locally served file, but will work on an identical file that's on the internet.  ("Error" is written to the file if I use 127.0.0.1 or 192.168.1.7)  This script writes all the URLs on a webpage to a text file.

```
Dim fso, outFile
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set outFile = fso.CreateTextFile("output.txt", True)

'  The Chilkat Spider component/library is free.
set spider = CreateObject("Chilkat.Spider")

spider.Initialize "http://192.168.1.7/index.htm"
spider.AddUnspidered "http://192.168.1.7/index.htm"

success = spider.CrawlNext()

if success then 

For i = 0 To spider.NumOutboundLinks - 1
    outFile.WriteLine(spider.GetOutboundLink(i))
Next

else
    outFile.WriteLine("Error.")
end if
```

Here are some Apache access logs.

```
Apache's log, running the VBScript (http://192.168.1.7/index.htm)
... GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 208
... GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1" 200 365184
... GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1" 200 365184
Apache's log, loading the same from Firefox
... GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1" 200 365184
... GET /index_files/rsAItRhddGWakWTu2xcFYn5VJXiw_002.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 533363
... (additional accesses, with 200 and then different numbers)
```

Regarding this log, the file saved locally is a Google search results page.  (For testing. I won't be using this for Google.)  The VBScript will run on the live internet version, but not the copy served locally.  Firefox loads the file served locally, and it look identical to the live one.

My Firewall is turned off.
Apache 2.2;  Windows XP SP3

Comment: Does Apache's access logs show anything? Are you able to get the HTTP Status Code?

Comment: @StevenVondruska I added the Apache logs to the problem description, at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find your answer in the response to [Apache 500 Error due to User Agent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514110/apache-500-error-due-to-user-agent). Essentially, Apache has been set up to ignore requests with an empty UserAgent string. The response refers to a related [UserAgent/.htaccess question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063944/unable-to-submit-feed-in-sites-like-friendfeed-and-feedage).

See also [How to Block Unwanted Bots from Your Website with .htaccess](http://www.thesitewizard.com/apache/block-bots-with-htaccess.shtml)